# Link colors changing in Chrome but not in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css

As stated, the link color only changes in Chrome (my default browser).

Here is the code I put in my external CSS file:

```
a:link {text-decoration: none;}
a:hover { color:darkgray; }
a:active { color:darkgray; }  /* Don't underline links */

a:visited {color:darkgray;text-decoration: none;}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You have all three set to the same colour why would they change? http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/YdH65/

Comment: Do you mean they don't change from the default blue?

Comment: yes that is what i mean sorry for the lack of info

Comment: Off the top of my head, is `darkgray` definitely a defined CSS color? Have you tried setting a different color to check? If so, have you tried adding spaces after the semicolons? IIRC IE used to have some kind of issue with spaces in CSS.

Comment: i looked for safe colors and found a site that said it was one of them and the spacing did not fix it

Comment: I would try hex color rather than darkgray. Perhaps the browser doesn't recognize it as a color.

Comment: i tried hex colors first that is why i tried darkgray because my original color did not work

Comment: Regardless of the problem, which it looks like you've worked out, I'd recommend using hex over color names, in the name of good practice (subjective).  Or maybe I'm just a control freak and I don't like to leave it up to browsers to determine exactly what qualifies as "darkgray"...

Comment: Why would you leave it up to somebody else? It's your website, you should be in total control. :-)

Comment: I agree completely, but as i said before when the color did not show up in other browsers my first thought was that it may not work in said browsers but as i have found it was just a messed up code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the issue. While in chrome my text color also covers my links but as you can see I did not actually set the link color in a:link

still thank you all for the input

a:link {color: darkgray ;text-decoration: none ;}

a:hover { color: darkgray ; }

a:active { color: darkgray ; }
 /* Don't underline links */

a:visited {color: darkgray ;text-decoration: none ;}